# How to create a Multi Ring Donut chart using Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Anybody help me to create a multi ring donut chart using google chart ?

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut

I need like following image with multilevel colors. 
[image]

Comment: there aren't any configuration options in google's pie chart that will result in the requested chart -- you could try stacking google pie charts on top of one another, with varying `pieHole` values -- but this would be tedious and difficult to produce dynamically, in terms of the number of rings...

Answer (score 0):

This was possible with the [Google Image Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/gallery/pie_charts?csw=1), which has been deprecated in 2012. It seems to still be up and running, it's just not maintained anymore.

With that API, it was (and still is) possible to create concentric pie charts such as the one below

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chd=s:Yr3,ff9&cht=pc&chs=300x200&chxr=0,20,45|1,25,50
```

which yields the following pie chart

[image]

Also you can play with the API and easily create your own pie charts here:
http://www.jonwinstanley.com/charts/

Supporting this kind of concentric Pie chart in the new Google Charts API is still [an open issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/786)

Comment: I got this solution but it is deprecated.So , I am trying to get something with google-visualization.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's has been a long time ago but here's one way you can do this, using google charts:

But, I removed the subtitles because they interfere in the position of objects, i think it's easier and better if we do our subtitles . Then i just made some drawings e maths to achieve this.

You can control the size and pieHole with 3 variables.

If you need more rings you need to replicate the logic of the first pie hole, but your code will grow kkkk.

```js
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
      
        //control is here
        let larguraGraficoFora = 400;
        let alturaGraficoFora = 400;
        let furoGraficoFora = 0.8;

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Sabor de Pizza', 'Quantidade'],
          ['portuguesa',     30],
          ['frango com catupiry',     30],
          ['calabresa',     30],
          ['alguma doce',     30],
        ]);

        var options = {
          width: larguraGraficoFora,
          height: alturaGraficoFora,
          chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:'100%',height:'100%'},
          pieHole: furoGraficoFora,
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donut_1'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
        
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Effort', 'Amount given'],
          ['c#',     30],
          ['python',     30],
          ['javascript',     30],
          ['sql server',     30],
          ['php',     30],
        ]);

        var options2 = {
            legend:'none',
          width: larguraGraficoFora*furoGraficoFora,
          height: alturaGraficoFora*furoGraficoFora,
          chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:'100%',height:'100%'},
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          legend: 'none'
        };

        var chart2 = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donut_2'));
        chart2.draw(data2, options2);
            ajustePosicaoPieCentral(larguraGraficoFora, alturaGraficoFora, furoGraficoFora);
      }
      
      
        function ajustePosicaoPieCentral(largura, altura, furo){

            yt = altura*(1+furo)/2.0;
            xt = largura*(1-furo)/2.0;

            var css = document.getElementById('donut_2');
            css.style.transform = "translate("+xt+"px, -"+yt+"px)";
        }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="donut_1" ></div>
       <div id="donut_2"></div>
```